# How to improve performance? Working with pandas

Tags: performance, loops, for-loop, vectorization, apply

i am looking to speed up my code. I have tried looking into vectorization and apply etc. But i am not sure on how to implement that on my piece of code. Hopefully someone can help me.

```
for j in df.col1.unique(): #this is the big problem
    temp = df.col2[df.col1 == j]

    for k in range(1,len(temp)+1):
        colName = 'col2' + str(k)
        value = temp.iloc[k-1]
        df.loc[df.col1 == j, [colName]] = value
```

If there are any questions about the code please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The current code has a quadratic complexity due to the expression like `df.col1 == j` and `df.col1 == j` iterating over the whole dataframe executed likely a lot of time. The solution is to use a **`groupby`**. Here is an untested example:

```py
groupedDf = df.groupby('col1')
for j,locDf in groupedDf:
    temp = locDf.col2

    for k in range(len(temp)):
        colName = f'col2{k+1}'
        value = temp.iloc[k]
        df.loc[groupedDf.indices[j], [colName]] = value
```

It should be even faster to assign all the columns using. Here is another untested example:

```py
groupedDf = df.groupby('col1')
for j,locDf in groupedDf:
    temp = locDf.col2
    colNames = [f'col2{k+1}' for k in range(len(temp))]
    df.loc[groupedDf.indices[j], colNames ] = temp
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the performance has gone up! Appreciate the time you put in

Comment: @QuestionMan You are welcome. Do not forget to validate the answer if it solved the problem.